# kotlin, Flow how does the flowOn change the context

Tags: kotlin-coroutines, kotlin-flow

Having code

```
       CoroutineScope(Main).launch {

            println( "+++ ========= CoroutineScope(IO).launch ${Thread.currentThread().name}" )

            flow {
                (1..10).forEach {
                    println( "+++ in Flow block() forloop ($it), in ${Thread.currentThread().name}" )
                    emit(it)
                }

                println( "+++ in Flow block(), after forloop, ${Thread.currentThread().name}")
            }.flowOn(Dispatchers.IO)
                .collect {
                    println("+++ collect's FlowCollector.emit lambda(); $it")
                    println( "+++ collect's FlowCollector.emit lambda(); in ${Thread.currentThread().name}" )
                }
}
```

and got the printout as

```
I: +++ ========= CoroutineScope(IO).launch main
I: +++ in Flow block() forloop (1), in DefaultDispatcher-worker-1
I: +++ in Flow block() forloop (2), in DefaultDispatcher-worker-1
I: +++ in Flow block() forloop (3), in DefaultDispatcher-worker-1
I: +++ in Flow block() forloop (4), in DefaultDispatcher-worker-1
I: +++ in Flow block() forloop (5), in DefaultDispatcher-worker-1
I: +++ in Flow block() forloop (6), in DefaultDispatcher-worker-1
I: +++ in Flow block() forloop (7), in DefaultDispatcher-worker-1
I: +++ in Flow block() forloop (8), in DefaultDispatcher-worker-1
I: +++ in Flow block() forloop (9), in DefaultDispatcher-worker-1
I: +++ in Flow block() forloop (10), in DefaultDispatcher-worker-1
I: +++ in Flow block(), after forloop, DefaultDispatcher-worker-1
I: +++ collect's FlowCollector.emit lambda(); 1
I: +++ collect's FlowCollector.emit lambda(); in main
I: +++ collect's FlowCollector.emit lambda(); 2
I: +++ collect's FlowCollector.emit lambda(); in main
I: +++ collect's FlowCollector.emit lambda(); 3
I: +++ collect's FlowCollector.emit lambda(); in main
I: +++ collect's FlowCollector.emit lambda(); 4
I: +++ collect's FlowCollector.emit lambda(); in main
I: +++ collect's FlowCollector.emit lambda(); 5
I: +++ collect's FlowCollector.emit lambda(); in main
I: +++ collect's FlowCollector.emit lambda(); 6
I: +++ collect's FlowCollector.emit lambda(); in main
I: +++ collect's FlowCollector.emit lambda(); 7
I: +++ collect's FlowCollector.emit lambda(); in main
I: +++ collect's FlowCollector.emit lambda(); 8
I: +++ collect's FlowCollector.emit lambda(); in main
I: +++ collect's FlowCollector.emit lambda(); 9
I: +++ collect's FlowCollector.emit lambda(); in main
I: +++ collect's FlowCollector.emit lambda(); 10
I: +++ collect's FlowCollector.emit lambda(); in main
```

Not sure if my understanding is correct here but I guess:

The CoroutineScope(Main).launch { ... } block runs on the main thread, so the flow { ... } block runs on the Main dispatcher.
Inside the flow, when it uses `collect`, it runs on the IO dispatcher context  due to `flowOn(Dispatchers.IO)` (it changes the context for  the downstream operators (such as collect)).

But why the the code in `.collect {...}` block

```
.flowOn(Dispatchers.IO)
                .collect {
                    println("+++ collect's FlowCollector.emit lambda(); $it")
                    println( "+++ collect's FlowCollector.emit lambda(); in ${Thread.currentThread().name}" )
```

gave printout the `${Thread.currentThread().name}` as `"main":

```
I: +++ collect's FlowCollector.emit lambda(); 10
I: +++ collect's FlowCollector.emit lambda(); in main
```

and the code in `flow{...}` block

```
flow {
                (1..10).forEach {
                    println( "+++ in Flow block() forloop ($it), in ${Thread.currentThread().name}" )
                    emit(it)
                }

                println( "+++ in Flow block(), after forloop, ${Thread.currentThread().name}")
            }
```

gave the `${Thread.currentThread().name}` as `DefaultDispatcher-worker-1`:

```
I: +++ in Flow block() forloop (10), in DefaultDispatcher-worker-1
I: +++ in Flow block(), after forloop, DefaultDispatcher-worker-1
```

Answer (score 2):

[Documentation for flowOn](https://kotlinlang.org/api/kotlinx.coroutines/kotlinx-coroutines-core/kotlinx.coroutines.flow/flow-on.html) is very clear that it applies to upstream, not downstream:

> This operator is composable and affects only preceding operators that do not have its own context. This operator is context preserving: context does not leak into the downstream flow.

Which actually makes sense. While items in flows go downwards, execution flow goes upwards. When we collect the flow, we invoke its bottom-most operator, which in turn calls an operator above it and so on. Operators below `flowOn` are not yet affected by it.

Also, names of threads reference `DefaultDispatcher`, because `Dispatchers.IO` and `Dispatchers.Default` reuse same threads.